# Prevent long list item from moving below bullet

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have an HTML list that uses "inside" positioning for its items. Unfortunately, any item without spaces gets forced to the area below its bullet. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? This problem occurs in Chrome/Edge, but not Firefox.

Here's how I want the list to look:
[image: desired result]

And here's the actual result (note the empty line next to the last bullet):
[image: actual result]

```css
ul {
  width: 16rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style-position: inside;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Ordinary Item (ok)</li>
  <li>Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text (ok)</li>
  <li>NoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpace (BAD!)</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the browser sees the bullet as a word separated from the text next to it. It will then break after it if you use `word-wrap: break-word;` or `word-break: break-word;`.

The other thing you could do is use `word-break: break-all;`.
But then it will also break in the middle of a word for long lines (like the 2nd one), which is something we don't want.

```css
ul {
  width: 16rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Ordinary Item (ok)</li>
  <li>Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text (ok)</li>
  <li>NoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpace (BAD!)</li>
</ul>
```

I don't think what you're asking is possible using dedicated properties.
Nevertheless, you can fake it. Remove the original bullets and display new ones using the pseudo-element `::before`.

```css
ul {
  width: 16rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style-type: none; /* removes the original bullets */
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.2rem; /* Should be the same as in li::before */
}

li::before {
  content: '•';
  line-height: 1.2rem; /* Should be the same as in li */
  font-size: 1.2rem; /* Should be the same as the line-height */
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 0.6rem; /* Change this to your liking 
}
*/
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Ordinary Item (ok)</li>
  <li>Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text (ok)</li>
  <li>NoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpace (BAD!)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like using `::before` is the only way to achieve a good, cross-browser result.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `word-break: break-word;` or `word-wrap: break-word;` or `overflow-wrap: break-word;` in your CSS like in attached code.

Try it, it will surely work and if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

```css
ul {
  width: 16rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style-position: inside;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;/*Or*//*word-break: break-word;*//*Or*//*word-wrap: break-word;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>UL</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>Ordinary Item (ok)</li>
  <li>Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text (ok)</li>
  <li>NoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpaceNoSpace (BAD!)</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, that approach removes the empty space in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Do you have a cross-browser solution?

Comment: @mfluehr I have edited my answer and added `word-wrap: break-word;`, you can try addding this also, It will work in all browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same result in Firefox (empty line next to the last bullet).

Comment: @mfluehr I have edited my answer and added `overflow-wrap: break-word;`, you can try it, it might solve your issue.

Comment: @mfluehr Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?